# Online platform for chess coaches to discuss syllabus and pedagogy

Tags: training, online, recommendations, coach

There are many online platforms for chess players to have discussions. Such platforms include websites that are predominantly made to play chess (such as chess.com, lichess.org, etc.) as well as forums and social networking platforms (such as google groups, whatsapp groups, etc).

In many platfroms, experienced players share material for free.
**Is there an online platform for chess coaches to discuss chess syllabus and methods to coach chess (rather than the chess material) ?**
(preferably, an open platform rather than a closed one).

*Context:* I like chess coaching. For a long time, the order of the material in chess books for beginners felt strange to me. There are some exceptions, such as 'the steps method' that seem to offer a well-organised syllabus. In contrast, for intermediate (not just past-beginner) and advanced levels, there are many organised resources.
I would like to be part of an online platform where coaches discuss the syllabus (and other stuff like which training methods are proved more scientific, but NOT chess material itself).

PS: I hope that such a platform would make it easier to research on chess training methods. More importantly, I feel that such discussions are necessary to improve chess coaching for beginners.

Comment: Negative-voters, could you explain why?

Comment: A whatsapp group is created for this purpose ([invite link](https://chat.whatsapp.com/HbhZLSP40KhJQKvAa4ejm4)). Researchers working on chess training methods are also welcome in that group.